# Is babel-loader still required with webpack 4.7.x?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I wanted to understand if I need to add `babel-loader`, `babel-core` if my project has `webpack` version `4.7.0`?

Initially I did not add `babel-loader`, and my code which contained ES6 compiled just fine and browsers got ES5.

If I do add `babel-loader`, I see the following warning in my `npm` or `yarn` tool `install` commands:

```
warning " > babel-loader@7.1.4" has unmet peer dependency "babel-core@6".
```

Hence I ask this question if I still need to add it as a `devDependencies` and configure it in the webpack configuration file to pre-process my `.js` files. I did not find documentation very clear about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is still required as `devDependency`. You will need `babel-loader`, `babel-core` and `babel-preset-env`. Webpack 4 (or for that matter v4.7.0 which released today) essentially changes nothing.

As far as your webpack's behavior is concerned, it is rather strange. Can you share your config which I can replicate at my end?

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Will share my code in few days as I&#39;m travelling. Could it be that `babel*` dependencies are added by `webpack`/`webpack-cli` transitively?

Comment: My apologies, without using `babel-loader`, it was still bundling the ES6 code. It was working because Chrome and FF now support the arrow function syntax. After installing `babel-loader`, `babel-core` and `babel-preset-env`, the bundled code has ES5. Thanks for pointing this out.